# How to make webhookcontroller active?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a chatbot in facebook messenger using dialogflow for the webhook i'm using visual studio c# .

I want to send a message to the user in chatbot messenger in a specific moment.

I have different two controller , the first one is for intent fulfillment:

```
namespace WebhookReceiver.Controllers
{

public class FirstController : ApiController
{
    GlobalClasses gc = new GlobalClasses();


    public string Get()
    {
        return "OK";
    }


    public int Get(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }


    public ApiAiResponse Post([FromBody]JObject jsonRequest)
    {
        using (WebhookReceiverModelDataContext ctx = new 
   WebhookReceiverModelDataContext())
        {


            ApiAiRequest request = jsonRequest.ToObject<ApiAiRequest>();

            ApiAiResponse response = new ApiAiResponse();

            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(request.result.parameters.ToString());


            if ("input.data".Equals(request.result.action.ToLower()))
            {

                                speechLang = "xxxx";
                                source = "NoResult";
                            }
```

The second controller i have created to send broadcast message( i don't know how to call this controller when action input.data ( in firstcontroller) is called.

I'm saving PSID of the user to send broadcast message in another moment (when an event will be online) .

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var querystrings = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    if (querystrings["hub.verify_token"] == "xxxx")
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(querystrings["hub.challenge"], Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    var signature = Request.Headers.GetValues("X-Hub-Signature").FirstOrDefault().Replace("sha1=", "");
    var body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (!VerifySignature(signature, body))
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebhookModel>(body);
    if (value._object != "page")
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    foreach (var item in value.entry[0].messaging)
    {
        if (item.message == null && item.postback == null)
            continue;
        else
            await SendMessage(GetMessageTemplate(item.message.text, item.sender.id));
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

private bool VerifySignature(string signature, string body)
{
    var hashString = new StringBuilder();
    using (var crypto = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSecret)))
    {
        var hash = crypto.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
        foreach (var item in hash)
            hashString.Append(item.ToString("X2"));
    }

    return hashString.ToString().ToLower() == signature.ToLower();
}

/// <summary>
/// get text message template
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">text</param>
/// <param name="sender">sender id</param>
/// <returns>json</returns>
private JObject GetMessageTemplate(string text, string sender)
{
    return JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        recipient = new { id = sender },
        message = new { text = text }
    });
}

/// <summary>
/// send message
/// </summary>
/// <param name="json">json</param>
private async Task SendMessage(JObject json)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync($"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token={pageToken}", new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    }
}
```

Have you any idea how to send notification  message using this webhook for users who are subscribed in the bot ?
I want to get the timer from the database . The schema database will be like this :

```
ID | Message | Event | EventDate | 1 | text text | Birthday | 13/04/2018 17:05
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you try to rephrase it by explaining your *business* need, not starting from what you think is the solution ("make the 2nd controller active")? And then what you tried so far

Comment: @NicolasR thank you , i reformulated the question. Can you please help me

Comment: Just to be sure, your source code seems not to use Microsoft Bot Framework. Do you use it? If not, please remove [botframework] tag from your question